# Why AJAX POST type is so slow in Symfony2?

Tags: jquery, symfony

This is the JS:

```
(function($) {
     $('#jQueryObj').click(function() {
         $.post('routing', {not important}, function(response) {
             console.log(response);
         });
     });
})(jQuery);
```

This is the Symfony2 controller action:

```
public function ajaxAction()
{
    return new Response('Why is so slow??');
}
```

The response is very slow, 5.02 seg, dev and prod environment. 
However with the GET method the response comes in 13 ms but I need to use POST.

Someone can help me and explain why.

Thanks

Comment: Use tool like [webgrind](http://code.google.com/p/webgrind/) to find the root of the problem. What does server log say, btw?